# Transfer data to new excel worksheet from Visual Basic 6

Tags: excel, vb6, worksheet

Good day to all!

I need some help on how could I transfer a data from VB6 to a new excel worksheet, like for example, I want to be able to select the previously created excel file, add a new sheet and save data onto it.

Here is what I currently have with my project:

```
Public Sub ExptExcel()

Dim ADAExcelExpt As String
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset

With CommonDialog1
 .CancelError = True
 .InitDir = "c:"
 .DialogTitle = "Save Excel File"
 .Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls|Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xslx"
 .Flags = cdlOFNExplorer Or cdlOFNHideReadOnly Or cdlOFNLongNames
  On Error Resume Next 'trap the cancel error
 .ShowOpen
End With

 If Err = cdlCancel Then 'user cancelled
'Exit Sub or msgbox "User cancelled."
    Exit Sub
'or whatever
 End If


 'exit if no file selected
 If CommonDialog1.FileName = "" Then
    Exit Sub
 End If

  ADAExcelExpt = "E:\Remittance Report\PrintSource.mdb"
  conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & ADAExcelExpt & ";"
  conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient

  Set RS = conn.Execute("Select FAGYDES, DedCode, FSERIAL, RANK, FULLNAME, DedAmt, FDEDDESC, FFULDESC, Datefm from tblPrintDeduct")

  'Create a new workbook in Excel
  Dim oExcel As Object
  Dim oBook As Object
  Dim oSheet As Object
  Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
  Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

  'Add headers to the worksheet on row 1
  oSheet.Range("A1:I1").Value = Array("AGENCY", "DEDCODE", "AFPSN", "RANK", "FULLNAME", "AMOUNT", "DEDTYPE", "DESCRIPTION", "DATE")
  'Transfer the data to Excel

  oSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset RS

  oBook.SaveAs (CommonDialog1.FileName)
  oExcel.Quit
  MsgBox ("File Exported!")

  'Close the connection
  RS.Close
  conn.Close

 End Sub
```

This sub parameter only exports the data that I have in a form to a new workbook.

And this is the export procedure:

```
Public Sub ExportToXL()

Const SheetSize = 65000     'Number of records per Excel sheet

Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim wkbWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim wksWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rngYCursor As Excel.Range, rngXCursor As Excel.Range
Dim ADAExcelExpt As String
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
'Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Long, lngPN As Long
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With appExcel
    .Visible = True
    .UserControl = True
    Set wkbWorkBook = .Workbooks.Add
End With

With wkbWorkBook.Worksheets
    While .Count > 1
        .Item(1).Delete
    Wend
    Set wksWorkSheet = .Item(1)
End With

With wksWorkSheet
    lngPN = 1
    .Name = Me.cboDeduc.Text & " " & lngPN
    Set rngYCursor = .Range("A2")
    .Range("A1:I1").Value = Array("AGENCY", "DEDCODE", "AFPSN", "RANK", "FULLNAME", "AMOUNT", "DEDTYPE", "DESCRIPTION", "DATE")
End With

  ADAExcelExpt = "E:\Remittance Report\PrintSource.mdb"
  conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & ADAExcelExpt & ";"
  conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient

  Set RS = conn.Execute("Select FAGYDES, DedCode, FSERIAL, RANK, FULLNAME, DedAmt, FDEDDESC, FFULDESC, Datefm from tblPrintDeduct")

        While True
        For i = 1 To SheetSize
            Set rngXCursor = rngYCursor
            If RS.EOF Then GoTo ExitSub
            For Each fld In RS.Fields
                rngXCursor.Value = fld.Value
                Set rngXCursor = rngXCursor.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
            Next
            Set rngYCursor = rngYCursor.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
            RS.MoveNext
        Next i
        'MsgBox ("File Exported!")
        Set wksWorkSheet = wkbWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(After:=wksWorkSheet)
        With wksWorkSheet
            lngPN = lngPN + 1
            .Name = Me.cboDeduc.Text & " " & lngPN
            Set rngYCursor = .Range("A2")
            .Range("A1:I1").Value = Array("AGENCY", "DEDCODE", "AFPSN", "RANK", "FULLNAME", "AMOUNT", "DEDTYPE", "DESCRIPTION", "DATE")
        End With
    Wend

'End With
   ExitSub:
RS.Close
Set rngXCursor = Nothing
Set rngYCursor = Nothing
Set RS = Nothing
Set wksWorkSheet = Nothing
Set wkbWorkBook = Nothing
Set appExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Regards,

Aron